# Rails loses nested attribute children on form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I have a has_one relationship that must exist:

```
has_one :child, :dependent => :destroy
validates_presence_of :child
```

In my controller I build the child on new with:

```
@parent.build_child
```

When the form is submitted with errors, the render ends up losing the built child.  This causes my fields_for to be blank, thus preventing the user from inputting the required child field(s).  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you realize that `build_` methods aren't saving anything to DB? Why do you expect your child to be saved through redirections? The common approach to render `edit` view again with displaying info about error(s). Note: `render`, not `redirect_to`. Thus, your view will be populated with your incomplete data as you expect it to.

Comment: I am rendering not redirecting.  Sorry that wasn't clear, I changed it in the post.

Comment: So you're calling `@parent.build_child` and then what? You render some view to fill data about the child (that sill isn't stored in the DB)? The result of filling the form is passed to the `children_controller#create`, right? Is it the place where you're trying to access your `child` through the `@parent`?

Comment: When you render the form again after the object does not save, are you calling this again? `@parent.build_child`

Comment: I call it in the "new" action in the controller, so I assume it would be getting called again.  When I output the child I get it the first time the new page is hit, but then nil after it is re-rendered.

Comment: Its hard to answer this question with the amount of information provided, obviously people are asking a lot of question to your question. Please post more code and a better description.... are you saying you have a nested form, and when that form does a POST and fails, on the roll back to that page, the fields are blank? Make the question less open ended and you'll get better results

Comment: Yes, the built children are lost on what you call the "roll back."

Comment: Can you post what the build_child method looks like? I am having the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
before_filter :build_child, :only => [:new, :edit]
```

Was supposed to be:

```
before_filter :build_child, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
```